# Volunteer undergraduate research system feels wrong?

Tags: phd, research-process, research-undergraduate, literature-review

I am a PhD student at a large state university system. The system hosts a program that encourages undergraduates to get involved in research on a volunteer basis (suggested weekly commitment: 6 hours during a 'regular' academic semester). The projects hosted on the system varies greatly (from data collection to data analysis to manuscript preparation), and I am considering using it to recruit an undergraduate to assist in a systematic literature review. If I recruited a student, they would stand to gain:

- Practice in conducting data extraction for articles for a systematic literature review
- Practice manuscript preparation
- Authorship (nb: if it leads to an accepted publication)
- etc...

When I was an undergraduate, I greatly appreciate the opportunity to participate in the research process. However, I was paid for the contributions (in both cash and credit-hour situations). I feel extractive utilizing labor that is volunteered. I have spent considerable time trying to find an in-house university scholarship/funding source for this activity, but to no avail.

While I realize this system must have been vetted and supported by numerous academics with research experience, I feel strange using it. Is it ethical to use this volunteer system? Or should I simply put more time into finding a funding source for the student?

I was also considering setting aside part of my PhD salary for the undergraduate student, but I realize this has tax and legal ramifications beyond my knowledge.

---

Updates from initial comments:

In general, I agree with the answer posted by @AnonymousPhysicist [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109882/should-professors-pay-undergraduate-students-doing-research-in-their-labs). So the question really is, *should* I still make use of this resource? I would be interested in prioritizing the student well-being, uplifting their success, and trying to leverage the project into tangible monetary and career-advancing rewards for them (conferences, presentations, thesis project, references, etc).

- All the projects (nearly 200 in the 2019-2020 academic year) on this system were based on the premise of volunteering (no cash payments or course credit)
- The primary purpose of the program is to foster undergraduate interest and participation in the research process, and to encourage students within the university to pursue careers in research
- My PhD stipend is meager, but I can't complain given what's going on with COVID-19

Comment: So you're saying they receive neither money nor course credit?

Comment: One possible way to think about it would be the legal standard for unpaid internships: is the *primary* purpose to educate the student, or to get work done?

Comment: Also related https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/119460/should-undergraduate-researchers-expect-payment

Comment: "I was also considering setting aside part of my PhD salary for the undergraduate student" If you are one of the 99.9% of PhD students who is poorly paid, don't.

Comment: Updated question to reflect comments

Comment: If I understand the system correctly, there is nobody forcing the undergraduate students to participate--it's entirely their choice to become involved. If that's the case, then those students that enroll are (presumably) those with a genuine interest in learning how to do academic research. While financial compensation is always a nice bonus, the real value for these students lies in your mentorship. In that regard, I would encourage you to make use of the system even if you can't find a way to have the students paid...

Comment: ...for their time. I think that it would be a real shame for a keen and motivated undergrad to miss out on an opportunity to be guided by someone with a passion for mentorship like yours.

Comment: @RobertBahensky A 6 hour commitment is about the equivalent of a 2 credit hour semester class. An unpaid project favors students who don't need to otherwise work to fund their schooling.

Comment: @mkennedy I don't disagree with you that unpaid research positions might systemically discriminate against students who need to work to fund their schooling. It's a perfectly valid and true point. I just don't understand how it changes my argument. While the system might discriminate against certain students, the students that can afford to volunteer for something like this have, I would presume, an intrinsic motivation to participate. After all, there's a time and opportunity cost associated with doing something for free. I don't see how that should change OP's decision to be involved.

Comment: Let me share my own experience:

I've worked in a research group during my undergrad., didn't get paid, didn't get any course credit, have spent more than 9 hours a day, and published an article in Nature Physics without paying anything (doing & publishing research is expensive). In the end, it helped my career a lot, changed me personally & academically. Even though I didn't have much money as a student, it wouldn't have changed anything if they had paid me because I have learned a lot, and my PIs (I had two) spent a lot of time with me.

Comment: @RobertBahensky Obviously, mentoring a motivated undergraduate is good for the undergraduate, and is in general good for the mentor. As you acknowledge, it discriminates against certain students. I and others argue that perpetuating that discrimination is worse that the good that comes out of working with whatever students happen to be available.